# How to change location of iPhone app icon?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Okay, I am a noob. It must be simple but I stuck here.

I do rigth-click and choose 'select file'.

[image]

After I choose the file the dialogue appears:

[image]

**I want to keep my icons not in the root directory**. But I can't figure out how to do this. I tried different ways, even create project from scratch...

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bring image assets into Xcode they will all be in your application bundle's root directory at run time.

It appears that you've added a file named "icon@2x.png" to your project at one time already. Go to the project's summary page in Xcode click **Build Phases** and then expand the section titled **Copy Bundle Resources**. There you'll find the reference to the resources that will be copied to your bundle at run time.

More on bundle structures here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html

Anyway, the way I've done this in the past is to:

1. Remove the existing image duplicate from Xcode and from the folder structure in Finder.
2. Add a new folder in Finder call it "/AppIcons" (or whatever).
3. Copy all the app icons to that folder in Finder.
4. Drag the "/AppIcon" folder into your XCode project. I typically put images in an "/Images" subdirectory in the Xcode project. Again you can put it wherever you'd like.
5. In Xcode on the project summary panel, add your app icons from the folder "/AppIcons" by dragging / dropping or by right clicking and adding them as separate files.

Alternatively in the past when I've had problems with this sometimes Xcode will copy the app icons to the root project directory. If that happens, I make sure that I have the "/AppIcons" folder structure on disc (in Finder) and in my Xcode project. I add the app icons to the project, then move them to /AppIcons in Finder, and re-reference them all over again.

Your **Copy Bundle Resources** should then have the proper file reference. Note that my apps icons go in "/Images/AppIcons"

[image]

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would add the image files to your project with the name icon@2x.png. To do this right click where you want to add the files in xcode and click add file/s. Then search for your image and add them using the dialogue that pops up. - there is a check box so that you can either copy them to the projects destination folder which will copy them into you project folder or leave it unchecked (inadvisable) which would reference it's current location on your HDD. Make sure the file doesn't already exist in the project before doing this!

EDIT:

Sorry I forgot to mention then drag and drop the file from within xcode onto the image location box.

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 4 (I'm using 4.6.2) you will get this confusing message if you've just moved the target's info.plist file, but not corrected the location at the top of the summary panel.  Fix this and the icons will reappear, assuming they are added to the project, or if not you should now be able to drag them in without xcode insisting on making extra copies.

This tends to happen when you're starting a project and sorting out the mess of default file locations that xcode gives you.  I like my project structure to be 99% the same as the file system structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy fix. If the image you want as your App Icon resides outside of the root of your project, when you get that dialog just click "Yes", and then click delete on the newly created file in the root, and "Move to Trash".

The reference is still there and works without a hitch, since the file will still be in the root at runtime